# Error binding socket on heroku , not sure about using express

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, express, socket.io

this is my first node.js and socket.io application , i didn't use express ,I want to deploy the application on heroku  do i need to use it ? i mean i just did npm install socket.io on localhost and in my server file i.e game.js i have io = require("socket.io") and socket = io.listen(Number(process.env.PORT)) only and in one of the files where from where i am sending the message i have socket = io.connect();
so please tell me if i need to use express and how show i modify my existing application ?
I have given the link to the source of application

( https://github.com/bitgeeky/herokutest )

Although the Application works fine on localhost by changing the port no , to some port no like (8000) but Heroku error log on doing "heroku open" is  http://pastebin.com/MtB0z5vQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you haven't created a http server. I am assuming that you are creating a web application, since you are deploying to heroku. For that, you need to create a http server in nodejs.

Go through socket.io https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io

Also http://socket.io/#how-to-use

This should get you started

**Note:** You do not need express. But it will make your work easier in many ways. Depends on the type of application that you want to create.